# Triple nested JPA Entity to JSON - Spring Boot Project

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

So,
I have 3 @Entity classes

```
class Campaign
{
  @Id
  private long campaignId;
  //Other fields

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "campaign",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Question> questions;
}

class Question
{
  @Id
  private long questionId;

  //Other fields
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Choices> choices;

  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="CAMPAIGN_ID")
    private Campaign campaign;
}

class Choices
{
  @Id
  private long choiceId;

  //Other fields
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="QUESTION_ID")
    private Question question;
}
```

When I create and send a JSON

```
{
    "campaignName" : "Dummy Quiz Campaign",
    "campaignDescription" : "This is a dummy quiz campaign for testing",
    "noOfQuestions":2,
    "noOfChoices":3,
    "lastUpdatedTime":"2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z",
    "createdTime":"2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z",
    "questions":[
        {
            "question":"Question 1",
            "choices":[
                {"choice":"Choice 1"},
                {"choice":"Choice 2"},
                {"choice":"Choice 3"}
                ],
            "correctAnswer":"Choice 2"
        },
        {
            "question":"Question 2",
            "choices":[
                {"choice":"Choice 4"},
                {"choice":"Choice 5"},
                {"choice":"Choice 6"}
                ],
            "correctAnswer":"Choice 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

It is being created and mapped accurately. It is also being deleted accurately.

But when I am trying to getAllCampaigns()

```
@GetMapping("/api/campaign/all")
    public List<Campaign> getAllCampaigns() throws Exception 
    {
        return campaignService.getAllCampaigns();
    }
```

It is showing a jackson.bind error, when I tried to write the JSON to a file, it ended up having an infinitely nested JSON.

What I can do to retrieve the Campaigns and there mapped entities like in the format I have send it.

As for the tables,
3 Tables
Campaign Table
Question Table with Campaign_Id
Choices Table with Question_Id

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting the infinite recursion is because, the question is mapped in the campaign class and the campaign is mapped in the question class. This bi-directional relation causes the infinite recursion. This can be solved by using `@JsonManagedReference`, and `@JsonBackReference` annotations on the mappings. You can use the `@JsonManagedRefernce` annotation on the one to many relation and `@JsonBackReference` annotation on the Many to one relation. This should solve the recursion problem. You can get more info from [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion)  . Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

**Here you need to add @JsonIgnore Anotation like this:**

```
class Question{
@Id
private long questionId;

//Other fields
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "question",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Choices> choices;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="CAMPAIGN_ID")
@JsonIgnore
private Campaign campaign;
}
```